# Extracting value from string (regex help)

Tags: r, extract

I have a dataframe in which I would like to extract each city's temperature value.

For example, if i have a string that says `"NYC experienced a temperature of 35.5 degrees centigrade"`

how would I extract the `35.5`?

Comment: Are you already getting the city?  Is there ever any other number in the sentences? Like "NYC had a temperature of 35.5 degrees centigrade and a barometric pressure of 30.20 mm of mercury"

Comment: Yes, there will be other values in the sentence. But the temperature values are always followed by a `degrees centigrade`

Comment: Here are two ways, you can decide based on the application:
  
gsub("[^0-9.]+", "", "NYC experienced a temperature of 35.5 degrees centigrade")

or

readr::parse_number("NYC experienced a temperature of 35.5 degrees centigrade")

Comment: `gsub(".*[^.0-9]([.0-9]+)\\b ?(?=degrees).*", "\\1", "NYC experienced a temperature of 35.5 degrees centigrade", perl=TRUE)`

Comment: or `trimws(regmatches(vec, gregexpr("[.0-9]+ (?=degree)", vec, perl=TRUE)))` (where `vec` is your string(s)).

Comment: or [`str_extract(my_string, "[\\d.]+(?= deg)")`](https://tio.run/##PcyxCsIwFEbhPU9xyZSgdpFuioO7u1gp1@Q3BGyU2yu0Tx8rguM3nCO1PvJNWGY3quSSxBszzP0PtNuQPZ2PhOkFySgBkZgUw0LWt4Ced9q2TUsRSYCRAormJBxhjVkuPSYVDur@0zXZS9fF5rpyh/2389bX@gE)

Comment: Please update the question (via edit) with the new information, or give a better example closer to the real problem (including more than one number). Not everyone seeks through all comments to search for possible additional info.

Answer (score 1):

```
library(stringr)
string <- "NYC experienced a temperature of 35.5 degrees centigrade"
pattern <- "\\d+\\.\\d+"
temperature <- str_extract(string, pattern)
print(temperature)

[1] "35.5"
```

Comment: You may want to allow for negative temperatures.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the input string is `s` this reads each word into a separate data.frame column and then extracts the numeric column using `Filter` and finally converts the data.frame result to a scalar.  No regular expressions or packages are used.

```
Filter(is.numeric, read.table(text = s))[[1]]
## [1] 35.5
```

or equivalently as this pipeline

```
s |> read.table(text = _) |> Filter(f = is.numeric) |> as.numeric()
## [1] 35.5
```

If we have a vector of strings `ss` then

```
ss <- c(s, s) # test data

f <- function(x) Filter(is.numeric, read.table(text = x))[[1]]
sapply(ss, f, USE.NAMES = FALSE)
## [1] 35.5 35.5
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
string = "NYC experienced a temperature of 35.5 degrees centigrade"
pattern = r"\d+\.\d+"
temperature = re.search(pattern, string)
print(temperature.group())
```

should print:

```
35.5
```